# Gas cans should be on-topic per the Help Center

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, close-reasons, closed-questions

As stated in the question, filling a gas can at a gas station is a common home improvement task that enables me to perform other home improvement tasks at home.

> [How to easily fill a gas can at a modern gas pump?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/251143/how-to-easily-fill-a-gas-can-at-a-modern-gas-pump)
> Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.

I bought the gas can in the lawn care isle of a home improvement store.

Filling a gas can isn't a "car"-related activity... filling a car is easy because the pumps are designed for it. I have never used this gas can for filling a motor vehicle. I only use it for my lawn mower.

The pumps are *not* designed for the home improvement task of bringing gas home to use in tasks around the house. Hence the question.

Plenty of on-topic [gasoline](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gasoline) questions here because plenty of on-topic home improvement tasks require gas: [lawn-mower](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawn-mower), [generator](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generator), [chainsaw](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chainsaw), [pressure-washer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pressure-washer), etc.

General lawn maintenance questions are allowed and on-topic:
[Should general questions on lawn maintenance be considered on topic?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128/should-general-questions-on-lawn-maintenance-be-considered-on-topic) All of my general lawn tools require gas to run, and I don't know how to efficiently fill them up.

The help center states that *"tools, materials, and best practices for home improvement tasks"* are on topic.

This question is about a *material* and a *best practice* for home improvement task, one that is clearly a real problem/question based on the number of people in the comments who have experienced the same issue.

This question is on-topic and should be reopened.